# Searchable tags in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, tags

I'm building a database of spiders, organizing them by name, country, and region within that country.

The problem is that many of the spiders exist in multiple countries and regions within that country.

I want to be able to sort spiders by either country, or region, without having to enter a duplicate entry for every country or region that spider exists in.

For example: Say Spider A exists in the USA and Australia. In the USA it lives in the South and North West. In Australia it lives in New South Wales.

Is there a way I can make one entry for this spider, but tag it so it will show up when I search for spiders in USA>South or Australia>New South Wales?

Answer (score 1):

You want to record many-to-many associations between spiders and locations.  If you were using a database, you would have a separate table to record the associations:

**Spider table**

```
Name        Web/Hunter   Nocturnal   ...
Spider A
Spider B
Spider C
```

**Location table**

```
Name        Latitude   Annual rainfall   ...
Location 1
Location 2
Location 3
```

**Spider/Location table**

```
Spider    Location
Spider A  Location 2
Spider A  Location 3
Spider B  Location 1
Spider B  Location 3
Spider C  Location 2
```

A database system, such as Access, has the necessary functionality to record this type of information and to specify a report of spiders by locations and another report of locations by spider.

It is possible to use a spreadsheet system, such as Excel, to hold this type of information.  But it is not playing to the strengths of a spreadsheet so it is more difficult and less reliable.

You may know Excel and not Access.  However, I would be surprised if you did not find it easier to learn Access and use that than try to implement this in Excel.